# Font Awesome 5 Bundle via NPM

Tags: npm, webpack, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I'm trying to bundle only required Font Awesome 5 icons via webpack, but the icons are not replaced in the DOM.

1. I've added all required packages from the [documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/use-with-node-js#pro):

   ```
   yarn add -D @fortawesome/fontawesome
   yarn add -D @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-solid
   yarn add -D @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-regular
   yarn add -D @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands
   ```
2. The following custom JS is included:

   ```
   "use strict";

   import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome';
   import faCheck from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-regular/faCheck';

   fontawesome.icon(faCheck);

   function iconsDoneRendering () {
       console.log('Icons have rendered'); // No output in console
   }

   fontawesome.dom.i2svg({ 
       callback: iconsDoneRendering,
   })
   ```
3. The HTML template:

   ```
   <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css?v2.1.4"> <!-- contains fa-svg-with-js.css -->
   </head>
   <body>
       <ul class="fa-ul">
           <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="far fa-phone"></i></span>List item 1</li>
           <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="far fa-check"></i></span>List item 2</li>
       </ul>
       <script src="/js/app.js?v2.1.4"></script>
   </body>
   ```

The svg path is inside the bundled JS file, but I can't figure out which method needs to be called.

---

The following JS code solves the problem (since v5.0.2):

```
"use strict";

import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome';
import faCheck from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-regular/faCheck';
import faPhone from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-regular/faPhone';

fontawesome.library.add(faCheck,faPhone);
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, have you managed to solve it?

Comment: Are you seeing the CSS being added to the head of the document as I am?

Comment: I look like it's currently not possible: "We will need to make some changes in order to support what you have there. It's currently a high priority for us."

Comment: I see that you updated the question to include the answer (kinda confusing, but ok).

For anyone else wondering why this isn't replacing their icons, maybe you haven't included `fontawesome.dom.i2svg()` after adding them to the library. That was the step I was missing, which is not documented very well.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback – I've reverted the original question and added the solution. In my case the replacement works without the i2svg call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We just released version 5.0.2 and updated the @fortawesome NPM packages to fix a few bugs related to this. Make sure you upgrade before you try anything else.

The missing step of the above example is to add the icon to the library:

```
fontawesome.library.add(faCheck)
```

Comment: Thanks @rob-madole this is working perfectly. I appreciate the quick update.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly! I've fixed the sample above.

Answer (score 12):

I realize this is already answered, but I'd like to give some visibility to the full solution since the information above does not include how to execute the SVG icon replacement.

If you're loading Font Awesome 5 via NPM & WebPack for use in front-end HTML like I am, you will need to do something like this in your JS that's included in your bundle:

```
"use strict";

// Import FontAwesome: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/use-with-node-js
import fontawesome  from '@fortawesome/fontawesome';

// This enables using FontAwesome in CSS pseudo elements
// see: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js#pseudo-elements
fontawesome.config.searchPseudoElements = true;

// Icons should be imported individually to keep bundle size down
import faCheck from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-regular/faCheck';
import faPhone from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-solid/faPhone';
fontawesome.library.add(faCheck, faPhone);

// If really necessary, entire styles can be loaded instead of specifying individual icons
//import solid from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-solid';
//fontawesome.library.add(solid);

// Execute SVG replacement
fontawesome.dom.i2svg();
```

That last line is key, you have to execute SVG icon replacement manually.

Comment: This is outdated, https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js#pseudo-elements doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Agreed this is a bit out of date now. A more up to date and thorough answer can be found here instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53580347/1462775

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
fontawesome.library.add(faCheck);
```

instead of

```
fontawesome.icon(faCheck);
```

If it does not work, please update your question with your DOM template, to see how it's defined in there.