# How to integrate FontAwesome 5 Pro with React?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

Could someone advice me on how to integrate FontAwesome 5 **Pro** with React?

I know there are packages @fortawesome/react-fontawesome and for example @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular but is there a way how to include **pro version** of icons?

When I log in to FontAwesome website, I can download the pro-version JS but I guess that's of no use in React.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font Awesome 5 Bundle via NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47711951/font-awesome-5-bundle-via-npm)

Comment: @Tomasz: Yes, I've seen it but that's not really helpful because it doesn't involve Pro (paid) version. FontAwesome website explains how to use free version with React and how to use Pro version by including script tags but it doesn't mention how to use Pro version in React...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's how to integrate Font Awesome 5 Pro with React (2018):

1. Purchase a Pro licence from [Font Awesome's pricing page](https://fontawesome.com/pricing)
2. Upon success, ignore the success pages. You should be logged into Font Awesome. In the login state, go to this guide: [Font Awesome Installation Guide](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers#installing-pro).
3. If you are logged in and have a valid license key in your account, every code snippet in this tutorial will use your access token.
4. Now, you can install your license key globally via (A) `npm config set ...` or locally per project via (B) `.npmrc`. I recommend (B) so other team-mates can also install the pro package.
5. For (B), Go to your package.json directory and create a `.npmrc` file. In that file, paste the code snippet provided in the guide. It should look something like this:

   ```
   // .npmrc
   @fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
   //npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=<MY_AUTH_TOKEN_FROM_FONT_AWESOME>
   ```
6. Once done, you should now be able to install the pro packages. They are according to the official react adapter [react-fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome) available as the following npm packages:

   - @fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons
   - @fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons
   - @fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons
7. So now do `npm install @fortawesome/pro-<MY_ICON_WEIGHT>-svg-icons` to install the pro package of your choice.
8. Thereafter, continue usage as provided by the react-fontawesome package. Which should look something like this in your react code if you installed the light version and using the ['Library' method by react-fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome#build-a-library-to-reference-icons-throughout-your-app-more-conveniently):

   ```
   // app.js
   import { library, config } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
   import { fal } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons'

   library.add(fal)
   ```
9. Finally, usage looks something like this in a component file (available in both JS and TS flavours):

   ```
   // Foo.jsx
   import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

   const Foo = () => {
     return (
       <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fal', 'utensils']} />
     )
   }

   export default Foo
   ```

   And if you are into Typescript:

   ```
   // Foo.tsx
   import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
   import { IconLookup } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'

   const Foo = () => {
     const icon: IconLookup = { prefix: 'fal', iconName: 'utensils' }
     return (
       <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon} />
     )
   }

   export default Foo
   ```

Comment: This is a fairly exhausting answer. The bit I was missing was primarily NPM token mentioned by @Beau Smith. I didn't know anything like that even existed :-) Regarding to your response, it's just worth saying that if you use only a couple of icons from FontAwesome, you don't need to use the `library.add()` call and you can use the specific icons directly in FontAwesomeIcon component. (Saves some kilobytes)

Comment: I'm able to get the icon to show up but I can't seem to apply any styling to it

Answer (score 5):

**tldr;** Use `@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons`, `@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons` NPM packages.

I ran into this problem today, and I think the main question of how to use Pro version of the icons has not been addressed. The official docs aren't much help. This is what I had to do for using `faFilePlus` icon, the light version:

`import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faFilePlus } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons/faFilePlus';`

and then:

`<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFilePlus} />`

Note the use of `@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons` NPM package. This is undocumented anywhere in the FA's official docs and I had to dig through several places to arrive at this solution. The official docs only talk about the use of "free" icons but don't say where to find the equivalent NPM package for light, regular etc.

Also note that this does require NPM to be authenticated as mentioned in one of the answers.

Comment: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons/faFilePlus', That is what I get

Answer (score 4):

## You must use a TOKEN to access Font Awesome Pro via NPM.

Manually downloading the icons and installing them locally is an anti-pattern and not the way the Font Awesome team expects you to use Font Awesome Pro with Node and NPM.

Accessing to the Pro packages requires you to configure the @fortawesome scope to use the Font Awesome Pro NPM registry using your **TOKEN** which can be found in your Font Awesome account settings.

1. **Login to see your token**: https://fontawesome.com/account/services
2. **Navigate to this step-by-step tutorial** after logging in and it will contain your token in all the examples: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers#installing-pro
3. **Install react-fontawesome** and follow the examples to render icons: https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome

**Note:** If you're looking to use Font Awesome Pro in **React Native**, check out: [react-native-fontawesome-pro](https://github.com/shyaniv7/react-native-fontawesome-pro)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved it myself. What I did was to import `@fortawesome/react-fontawesome`. Then I manually downloaded the pro package of FontAwesome and from the folder `/advanced-options/use-with-node-js/fontawesome-pro-light` I copied desired icons (there are JS files such as `faUsers.js`) to my project folder and included these icons as well.

So at the beginning of the file I have something like

```
import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import faUser from '../font-awesome/faUser';
```

Then I used it

```
render() {
    return() (
         ...
         <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} />
         ...
    );
}
```

It's a little bit annoying because I need to manually import every single icon but I couldn't think of any better solution.

Comment: This is what you’ve been looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49565651/101290

Comment: Manually downloading the package might prove difficult to maintain in future upgrades etc. Please see if my answer helps? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be able to use them be adding the JS script and appropriate CSS files to your **index.html**

Let's say if you want to use the default font awesome without having any packages installed then directly include file in **index.html** as shown below

```js
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-+Ga2s7YBbhOD6nie0DzrZpJes+b2K1xkpKxTFFcx59QmVPaSA8c7pycsNaFwUK6l" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-7ox8Q2yzO/uWircfojVuCQOZl+ZZBg2D2J5nkpLqzH1HY0C1dHlTKIbpRz/LG23c" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I'm using React and Webpack. I use index.html only to include React root application so I can't use script tags. I need to include it somehow into JS with `import` directive.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work without having to import each icon, with

```
import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome'
import solid from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-solid'
fontawesome.library.add(solid)
```

And then using the icons as

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={solid.faPlusHexagon}/>
```

Comment: Yes, I know you can do this but it only works for public icons. Those public packages don't contain all the icons that pro version includes - for example there are no light versions (only regular and solid).