# Using font awesome pro with semantic-ui

Tags: font-awesome, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I just purchased FA-pro, and I tough semantic had a way to use it, but it is nowhere documented.
Any way to use Font awesome pro with semantic-ui ? (I'm using SUI React, but I already did an Icon wrapper to directly use SUI).

Answer (score 4):

Semantic UI has CSS compiled for the basic Font Awesome. That doesn't mean you are prevented from using whatever you want though. However, the `name` prop on Semantic UI React's `Icon` component is only going to help you validate for icon names in the free set.

In this case, the way you may want to go is just to include all of the styles that come with Font Awesome's Pro set in your project instead. You can still use SUIR's `Icon` component but you would define your icon classes with the `className` prop instead.

Take a look at Font Awesome's [basic use](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use) docs.

Once you include your pro fonts and css in your project's build process (whatever that is) then you should be able to do this: `<Icon className='far fa-stroopwafel' />`

Comment: I've tried doing just this, and it doesn't seem to work for me. I followed [this installation method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319363/how-to-integrate-fontawesome-5-pro-with-react) and added the `all.js` script element to my html header, and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using the pro version of font awesome, but I usually just do this

```
<Label size='medium' color='green'><FontAwesomeIcon icon='dragon'/>   Powerful for gaming</Label>
```

This will create  [image]