# How to make Font awesome 5 work with webpack

Tags: webpack, font-awesome

I'm trying to use Fontawesome in my Flask/webpack project.

The craziest thing is some point it worked then stopped, I changed something stupid, it worked again and finally it stopped working completely.

What I have:

package config:

```
  "devDependencies": {
        ...
        "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
        "webpack": "^4.19.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
        "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.3.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
         ...
    }
```

webpack config (rules section):

```
   test: /.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
        use: [{
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: '../fonts/',  
            publicPath: '../static/fonts' 
            }
        }]
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            'sass-loader'
        ]
    },
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
            "style-loader", 
            "css-loader", 
            "sass-loader" 
        ]
    },
```

webpack, entry section:

```
entry: {
        myStyles: './stles/myStyles.js'
    },
```

myStyles.js:

```
import fontawesome from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss";
import regular from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss";
import solid from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss";
import brands from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss";

fontawesome.library.add(solid, regular, brands)
```

The last line though caused the error in Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

I also tried to add imports into my entry scss and it worked at some point, then stopped:

```
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands";
```

So, finally in my template I have:

```
<i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-fw"></i>
```

and what I see is only squares.

I checked Chrome, fonts are loaded (ttf, woff, woff2).

Please help. I already spent more than 6(!!!!) hours wasted on this problem and it's more than I spent on anything else related with webpack.

UPD I think I figured it out. I found that my public path was wrong, I mean this part of webpack config: publicPath: '../static/fonts' - it currently points to the static/fonts folder one level up from my html. First of all, relative path is wrong per se, secondly, a relative path will not work for other folders, third, I've changed it to the relative to the root: '/static/fonts' and it worked.

Comment: Did you find any solution to import it with scss?

Comment: @white_gecko I was wrong with paths, see the update of the question.

Comment: Regarding the inconsistent _"it worked"_, _"it stopped working"_ behavior: I had to `yarn build` instead of `yarn dev` to debug my font-awesome / webpack-loaders problems.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work on webpack 5 using Asset Modules?

Answer (score 101):

In my project ([HTML Starter](https://github.com/cichy380/html-starter-v2) with **webpack 4**.26.1) I added FontAwesome via two variants:

### 1. Installed and added

I just installed [FontAwesome Free](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers#installing-free) (*`v5.5.0`*)

```
npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

and I added to **`index.js`**

```js
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/fontawesome'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/solid'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/regular'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/brands'
```

> [Source code](https://github.com/cichy380/html-starter-bs4-webpack/blob/94865ac0b2283ee8cbd6df8b9b952a1eec8869fe/assets/index.js#L18-L22) / [Commit](https://github.com/cichy380/html-starter-v2/commit/94865ac0b2283ee8cbd6df8b9b952a1eec8869fe)

### 2. Used with the API / SVG

I [installed FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/setup/getting-started#using-node) (svg-core, brands-icons, regular-icons, solid-icons)

```bash
npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
```

and I added to JS file

```js
import { library, dom } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

library.add(fas, far, fab) 

dom.i2svg()
```

> [Source code with comments](https://github.com/cichy380/html-starter-bs4-webpack/blob/b97c1da4edb9ca96102bc9de7144255b1fa9fdfe/assets/scripts/vendor/fontawesome.js) / [Commits](https://github.com/cichy380/html-starter-bs4-webpack/commit/b97c1da4edb9ca96102bc9de7144255b1fa9fdfe#diff-45db9631e3dfb758fda24ae3fe147ee5)

Comment: If you're using Vue, then you need to use `vue-fontawesome` because the base library modifies the DOM in a way unsupported by Vue.

Comment: Great - first step was all that was needed for me.

Comment: For all of you using FontAwesome5 this is the import to use in your app.js: import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.css'

Comment: Why not import via sass/css?

Comment: Instead of `dom.i2svg()` I found that `dom.watch()` worked to turn on `<I>` tag replacement.

Comment: Re the first variant, `import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all'` works equally well in my case

Comment: With the API, how do you install only some icons to avoid a big bundle?

Answer (score 41):

This is what worked for me.

Taken from the user @ahbou on the webpacker issues page https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/619#issuecomment-430644035

on your console

```
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

inside your .scss file

```
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts'; 
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
```

Comment: This worked great for me. This approach is simpler than including via JS and seems like the "right" thing to do since these packages are just SCSS, after all... (Fwiw, if you're using npm instead of yarn, you do `npm install` instead of `yarn add`))

Answer (score 13):

this worked for me

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
```

> in: app/javascript/packs/application.js

my case: Rails 6 webpacker gem, webpack, yarn

installed via `yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

from https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/619#issuecomment-590454028

Answer (score 12):

First install the following,

```
npm install file-loader @fortawesome/fontawesome-free --save
```

And then in the webpack.config.js, Add

```
{
  test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
  loader: "file-loader",
  options: {
    outputPath: "../fonts",
  }
}
```

Finally,

```
$fa-font-path: '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts'; 
@import '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Yes, you probably need a file loader! I also needed to add one for the SVGs.

Comment: Prepended a `~` for node_modules dir and this answer worked

Answer (score 6):

Just import this file in your myStyle.js

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all'
```

or you can import only specific size of icons

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/light'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/regular'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/solid'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/brands'
```

I think fontawesome.library.add() is not needed.

Answer (score 5):

I am using the pro version, which is essentially the same in terms of usage, the ending of the name is '-pro' instead of '-free'.

I am importing the font awesome all.js file into my index.js file:

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/js/all.js'
```

And importing the css into my index.scss file:

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.css';
```

Comment: I didn't need the `~` for my `.scss` import but otherwise this was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone comes looking for a solution for implementing font awesome 5 (fa5) in symfony 4+ applications using webpack, the solution is the same as others have mentioned previously.

So firstly you will have to install fontawesome. Run
`yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`
on your terminal.

Then you simply require all.css and all.js in your app.js file. Incase it's not clear which app.js file I'm referring to here, you can find the app.js file in the `app-root/assets/js` directory.

`import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js';`

`import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';`