# webpack font awesome, dumping files at root

Tags: webpack, font-awesome

I have the webpack.config below, when I import font awesome in my index.js webpack is dumping all the font files at the root (dist). The font rule works in putting them in "fonts" subfolder but it's also dumping them at root in this weird format (export command).

If I don't import fontawesome its not creating the files at the root. I don't understand why it's doing this, any ideas on how to fix.

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");

const srcPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './src');
const stylePath = path.resolve(srcPath, './styles');
const bldPath = path.resolve('../MyApp/wwwroot/dist');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        master: path.resolve(srcPath, 'index.js'),
        style: `${stylePath}/style.css`
    },
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },
            {
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                include: srcPath,
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader' }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            publicPath: './fonts/',
                            outputPath: './fonts/',
                            esModule: false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: './images/',
                            publicPath: './images/',
                            esModule: false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: require.resolve("jquery"),
                loader: "expose-loader",
                options: {
                    exposes: ["$", "jQuery"],
                },
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    chunks: 'all',
                    name: 'vendor',
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/
                }
            }
        },
    },
    output: {
        path: `${bldPath}`,
        publicPath: '/wwwroot/dist/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: [`${bldPath}/**`],
            dry: false,
            verbose: true,
            dangerouslyAllowCleanPatternsOutsideProject: true
        }),
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].min.css'
        })
    ]
};
```

index.js > importing fontawesome...

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
```

result...

[image]

contents of one of these files...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was importing fontawesome 5 wrong, I ended up doing this in my entry js file (index.js). Now all the icons are available and no longer getting all the fonts dumped to the /dist root.

import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/fontawesome'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/solid'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/regular'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/brands'

Where I found the answer:

[How to make Font awesome 5 work with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376720/how-to-make-font-awesome-5-work-with-webpack)