# Font Awesome 5 - Self Hosting - Best and flexible integration?

Tags: font-awesome, self-hosting

I want to use SVG + JS for FA 5 (Pro) self-hosted. FA regards using the all.js which is > 3MB. Alternative I could use "certain styles" with smaller file sizes.

But I'm searching for a better integration - like a js searching for all used icons and loading only these instead of the whole library. Is there any recommendation?!

Comment: Although it's a bit of a broad question, I think it's a nice one. Another thought; are you aware that under normal circumstances, the resources are being cached on the client?

Comment: I'm aware of this, but the first/initial load will be very huge. Another thought may be some (FA-)server intelligence like saving all requested icons (per host) and serving them merged together.

Comment: Looks like this has already been answered. It doesn't do an automatic search for icons being loaded, but it definitely enables you to just load the ones you want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47711951/font-awesome-5-bundle-via-npm